# How do I post a "release" on github?

Tags: github, release-management

I have a few open source projects that I manage. I've been posting the `.tar.gz` releases for them to a directory on a webserver I run. I would like to post them to github. Is there a simple way to post the release and a signature for the release? My users aren't sophisticated enough to download the release with git; they want to download and install a `.tar.gz` file. Some of them may even want to verify the signature.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GitHub have just announced their new "GitHub Releases" feature, which sounds like exactly what you're after:

https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software

Comment: Is there a way to do so using Git command from any GIT client?

Comment: this is not useful at all, I still do not understand how to create a release, after reading this

Answer (score 9):

One nice option github supports is tagging, and automatic tar.gz/zip creation based on those tags. It makes publishing releases really easy.

http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html

On the commit/branch that you'd like to mark as a release, do

```
git tag <release_tag>
```

then

```
git push --tags
```

then, on github.com/user/repo/tags, you can see all tagged releases. You can link straight to those files, like in jimw's answer.

Comment: There are two problems with a simple tag. #1 - I can't digitally sign these `.tar.gz` releases. #2 - my users need the `configure` and `missing` and other `autoconf`-generated junk that doesn't belong in the git repository.

Comment: @vy32, you can now use [annotated tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_annotated_tags) for the first issue, and about the second - create a [git hook](http://githooks.com/) to do that

Answer (score 6):

Other awesome option might be distributing from http://bintray.com. It [integrates great with GitHub](http://blog.bintray.com/2013/06/05/bintray-github-synergistic-love-story/) and gives you so much more when distributing binaries.

Answer (score 2):

I you'd also like to upload other kinds of files (compiled binaries, ...) and edit github releases from the commandline with a rather easy-to-use tool, I made something for that. It's called [github-release](https://github.com/aktau/github-release). It's basically a user-friendly abstraction over the Github releases API. It's written in Go so I took the liberty of cross-compiling it for OSX/linux/windows/FreeBSD, and you can download the binaries from the [releases page](https://github.com/aktau/github-release/releases), of course.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author.

Comment: I still don't understand something. Where does the binary live within the repo? Do I have to create another branch with the file in it? Really confused.

Comment: Didn't realize that you can upload the binary directly to the release or with the github-release upload command.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch a tarball of any tag like so:

```
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tarball/2.5.4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few utilities to do what you need.

```
github_upload (Ruby) : https://github.com/github/upload
App::gh (Perl) : https://metacpan.org/module/App::gh::Command::Upload
```

Take your pick :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the github_upload script no longer seems to work.

Comment: I have a similar use case as you do - but haven't gotten around to using any of these tools yet. Good to know about the status of `github_upload`. Maybe you can give the perl one another shot. Try to use `cpanm` and have it figure out all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the GitHub [Downloads section](https://github.com/blog/742-new-uploader-downloads-screen) - no need for git at all to download files from there.

Comment: [Depreciated](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads), use [Releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) instead.