# Git can't see my *.exe

Tags: git, github

I added a subfolder to house my built project on Github.  Call the folder  /BuiltProject.  For some reason when I run git status I cannot see this file:

BuiltProject/my.exe.

How can I checkin my built project?

gitignore:

```
bin/
TestProject
/Sample.pro
*.vshost.*
ProjectName/app.config
/ProjectName.exe.config
```

Comment: try `git check-ignore -v` to see if it gives any additional info

Comment: @AndrewC - `git check-ignore -v *` showed nothing.  I ran it from the root.  First time I've used the command so maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Run it from it from the directory with your my.exe

Comment: Don't add binary files to git?

Comment: @zoska - What do people typically do?  I don't want to force my users to download an IDE and compile the app.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey github allows to to upload files for releases. There can you put your binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, some configuration tells git to ignore your `BuiltProject/my.exe` file.

In spite of this, you could add the file to the index by doing

```
git add --force BuiltProject/my.exe && git commit -m "adding binary"
```

If you want to know who is responsible for ignoring the file, there's [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v BuiltProject/my.exe
```

It will tell you the ignore file and the ignore pattern that leads to ignoring your file.

However, IMHO it's not common to include resulting binaries in source control. Either use [GitHub's Release feature](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) for uploading binaries attached to a label or set up a second repo that just holds the binaries where customers could download binaries of your software if people aren't interested in the sources.

Related reading:

- [which gitignore rule is ignoring my file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file)
- [How do I post a "release" on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951629/how-do-i-post-a-release-on-github)

Answer (score 1):

I ran `git status --ignored` and saw my file being ignored.  I ran

`git add -f BuiltProject/my.exe`

And now it can be committed.  I don't know why the file is ignored, but I guess this will bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's worth checking the following files for *.exe ignoring rule:

```
$HOME/.config/git/ignore
$GIT_DIR/info/exclude
```

Comment: I did not see these locations in my project.