# Upload Source Package to GitHub Release with Command Line

Tags: git, github

I have a large source package (tar.gz) that I would like to upload a GitHub repository as a new release.

I'm familiar with SourceForge's rysnc capability, but was wondering if it is possible to use the command line to upload source packages to a GitHub repository's release?

It takes a very long time to transfer the files using a web browser. What are my options, googling did not return much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link should answer your question on "command line to upload source packages to a GitHub repository's release"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9951817/6491187

direct link on github.
https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software

Answer (score 1):

You could use `curl` to do it easily like described in this post:

https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-09-25-releases-api/